# Java, XML - Bridging XML and Class Objects

Tags: java, android, xml, class, object

This is something kinda difficult to explain. I apologize.

So I just got my application to finally create new layouts onto my phone and it's nice that it can do all that. But the question is, can I make a new Java object and tie it to that certain layout?

I have an arraylist that lists class objects called Contacts. The class objects has variables like phone number, name, age, etc. Now how am I to make that one connect to the newly created layout and only that one without mixing it up with the other layouts?

This will be used as a way to save multiple contacts onto a list which when reopened, it will automatically list them all out with the information shown on the layout.

Any more information required will be provided.

Comment: do you want to use something called "ListView" ?

Comment: @pskink I'm assuming it is like an arraylist but for Views?

Comment: like this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html ?

Comment: @pskink it looks helpful! But from what I've skimmed, I don't think it answered my initial problem. :/

Comment: sorry, then i dont understand what you really want

Comment: @pskink it's fine. thanks for the tip!